# Put a JTextField search bar in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have to create a search `textField` object above a `JTable`. This JTable is inside a `JScrollPane`:
[image]

To reach my target I implement a Jpanel where I add the `JTextField` and the `Jtable`:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JTextField search = new JTextField();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(search, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.setViewportView(panel);
```

In this way I get the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default layout for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`. So you must set your panel's layout to `BorderLayaout`.

Change this

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

with

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```